# PHP - Function to skip strtolower() if variable contain "wikipedia.org"

Tags: php, string

My site allows users to enter URLs into a database.  I am using the code "$site = strtolower($site);" to make all of these URLs lower-case.

However, I just realized that Wikipedia URLs are case sensitive, so I would like to avoid using "$site = strtolower($site);" on Wikipedia URLs, all of which contain "wikipedia.org".

How could I write a function that will skip over the step "$site = strtolower($site);" if $site contains "wikipedia.org"?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Are you sure that Wwikipedia links are case sensitive?  They don't seem to be case sensitive to me...

Comment: Most URLs are case sensetive, the notable exception being those hosted on windows servers. I think it's a bad idea in the first place. What's the problem with storing URLs in their original case?

Comment: You do realize that the path is case sensitive on every URL, and it's only a matter of chance that most servers will do the right thing if you get the case wrong?

Comment: More sites than Wikipedia have case sensitive URLs.  I'd guess you're going to continue to have trouble with strategy.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia (and many other sites) have case-sensitive URLs.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Superm401/foo and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Superm401/Foo .

Comment: Why not revise your reasons for making them lower case?

Comment: I wonder if you had any luck with my method below. If you did, please feel free to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: I tried your function, by pasting it in my code and then adding "$site = urltolower($site);".  I can add upper-case URLs with your function in place.

Comment: @John: Are you also inputting the scheme? "NYTimes.com/TestSite" will not give the expected result (as PHP will parse all this as a PATH [which is normal]). "hp://NYTimes.com/TestSite"; will work (putting hp instead of http because of SO's automatic link detection, please replace).

Comment: @Andrew Moore: I don't understand.

Comment: @John: right now, $site contains "NYTimes.com/Whatever". It's missing the http:// in front, which causes PHP not to detect the domain (parse_url is a PHP function and I can't fix this unless I write a regex to extract the parts). Try $site=urltolower('http://'.$site);

Answer (score 9):

All URLs on *nix servers are case-sensitive. Some URLs on Windows servers are also case-sensitive.

**Edit:** The domain name is case-insensitive (actually, the client converts it to lowercase).

```
http://user:pass@domain.com/somedir/somefile.ext?someQueryString=someValue#fragment
=======----------==========--------------------------------------------------------

Legend:
    - : Case sensitive
    = : Case insensitive
```

**Note:** By specification fragments are supposed to be case sensitive but it is not implemented that way on all clients.

This is a very bad idea to do what you are trying to do. The best way would be to just lowercase the domain name.

**Edit 2:** Since you asked, here is a function that will properly lowercase a given URL (scheme and domain only):

```
function urltolower($url) {
    $parts = @parse_url($url);
    if($parts === FALSE) return FALSE;
    $url = '';

    if(!empty($parts['scheme'])) $url .= strtolower($parts['scheme']) . (($parts['scheme'] == 'file') ? ':///' : '://');
    if(!empty($parts['user'])) $url .= $parts['user'] . ((!empty($parts['pass'])) ? ':' . $parts['pass'] : '') . '@';
    if(!empty($parts['host'])) $url .= strtolower($parts['host']);
    if(!empty($parts['port'])) $url .= ':' . $parts['port'];
    if(!empty($parts['path'])) $url .= $parts['path'];
    if(!empty($parts['query'])) $url .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    if(!empty($parts['fragment'])) $url .= '#' . $parts['fragment'];

    return $url;
}
```

**`[mixed] urltolower($url)`**

Lowercases an URL. Returns **`FALSE`** on failure. Returns lowercased URL on success.

Example:

```
echo urltolower('HTTP://en.WikiPedia.org/wiki/PHP');
//echo's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP
```

Comment: I think my site is hosted on a Unix server, and when I type all caps in the address bar, it goes to my site name in lower-case letters (at least on Google Chrome).

Comment: @John: This happened only when your server is configured to use mod_spel or equivalent -- this is non-common.

Comment: @John: domain names are case-insensitive. So, let's say your domain name is example.com and you have a file called test.txt. EXAMPLE.COM/test.txt will work, EXAMPLE.COM/Test.txt won't, example.com/Text.txt won't, example.com/test.txt will.

Comment: Hmmm.  You have me thinking.  I might just drop the strtolower altogether.  I just want to avoid redundant entries in the database.  I. e., I don't want NYtimes.com and nytimes.com to both be in it.

Comment: @John: Then just lowercase the domain name.

Comment: Also, if you changed your mind, might want to change your accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah... is there an easy way to lower-case the domain only, or does it require a complicated regex?

Comment: @John: I just modified my post to include such a function.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(stristr($site, 'wikipedia.org') === FALSE){
 echo "doesn't contain wikipedia.org";
}else{
 echo "wikipedia.org!";
}
```

**Update**

Just a short note on storing urls in your database. It is NOT uncommon for a directory, file, username, password or parameter on a server to contain uppercase characters. Although the interpretation depends on the underlying OS, webserver and code I would strongly recommend to not use strtolower() for anything except maybe the domain and protocol.

Comment: Nice, didn't know there was a "stristr" function

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea.  URLs in general are allowed to be case-sensitive, so why would you throw away info?  If you do this, you'll have to add exception after exception.

Comment: It seems to me that all URLs except Wikipedia are case-insensitive.  Try typing in NYTIMES.com, and you're redirected to nytimes.com.

Comment: All domains are case-insensitive - this is not true for all URLS however

Comment: John, domains are case-insensitive (http://WIKIPEDIA.ORG goes to http://wikipedia.org too).  Paths are not.

Answer (score 0):

[stripos()](http://us.php.net/stripos) will tell you if a string exists at any point within another. Check that, and if it's not there, strtolower() will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Making a simple If condition can solve your problem.
Set your conditions for your requirements